# Problems with WFS in QGIS 3.22.16

Tags: qgis, wms, wfs

I am using QGIS version 3.22.16 LTR and I have problems using WFS services. I want to include the following WFS service in QGIS:
https://geoportal.umwelt.sachsen.de/arcgis/services/boden/bk50/MapServer/WFSServer?

If I want to add a layer to my project I get the following error:
Layer extent reported by the server is not correct. You may need to zoom on layer and then zoom out to see all features.[image]

If I deactivate the function "Only request features overlapping the view extent" I doesn't get the error. The map section is zoomed in very close and I only see data when I zoom out. Normally the map section is set to the full extent of the layer. In older QGIS versions the service works without problems.

I have a similar problem with the following WMTS:
https://geodienste.sachsen.de/wmts_geosn_dop-rgb/guest?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&Version=1.0.0

This service does not provide any data and the map section is zoomed in very close. In older versions of QGIS, this service can also be used normally.

What could be the reason for these problems?

Comment: the second url is a WMTS not a WMS

Comment: The WFS seems to work fine for me

Comment: Both services work fine under 3.28.7 when loaded into a GIS using 25833 and standard settings.

Comment: I know that it works fine under other versions. I would be interested to know what the problem is with version 3.22.16.

Comment: loads for me in 3.22.14, but maybe I'm not replicating your project environment.  What project CRS do you have set, and what is the area extent are you zoomed to?